# Compare dynamic JSON files - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I've read the various questions regarding JSON object comparison, and am relatively confident that I can implement a comparison. My query is regarding loading of source .json files dynamically into JSON objects for comparison.

My scope for this project has been amended, such that a dynamically loaded .json file is checked for changes at a given interval. The previous version of the application didn't require this, so the dynamic .json file was only loaded once. Below is the current implementation (single .json file only).

The jsdata.json file:

```
var jsArray = [
    {
        "Value1": "Hello!",
        "Value2": "Second!"
    },
    {
        "Value3": "Third!",
        "Value4": "Last!"
    }
]
```

The HTML file:

```
var jsScript = document.createElement('script');
jsScript.setAttribute('id', 'jsFile');
jsScript.setAttribute('src', 'jsdata.json');
document.head.appendChild(jsScript);

//psJSON is called, passing the x variable

function psJSON(x) {
    $(document).ready(function(e) {
        if (jsArray[x].Value1 == "Hello!") {
            alert("Hello!");
        } else {
            alert("Sorry!");
        }
    )};
}
```

This current code works fine for retrieving data from the jsdata.json file. However, if I were to add a second .json file, I wouldn't know how to address the two files individually.

Is the $(document).ready() function the best approach to this, or is there a better way?

Comment: Not enough known. Will update include items already in existence? Can new data simply replace old? Objective and criteria are not very clear. Also conflicts...in one place you say 2 files in another it is simply a recurring event set on interval

Comment: Basically I need to load a .json file after x seconds from the same URL as the original .json file, compare the two, and then call a function depending on whether changes to the file have been made.

Comment: Compare in what way...existing objects may have been deleted or updated or just new ones added?

Comment: Both. Existing objects may have been removed, new objects may have been added, or existing object values may have been changed. Basically, if fileA is not an exact replica of fileB, I want it to return a false reading.

Comment: can simply compare the 2 strings of json for that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all don't put variables in `.json` files.

You can make this work by using `$.getJSON()`. This will return a promise. Do this once for every json file you have. Afterwards use `$.when()` to for wait for all of them to be resolved.

Working example:
http://plnkr.co/edit/dFVbzzqRaZ03gfN9GWEo

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I've been playing with an ajax method, which would appear to work as planned, but I'm currently struggling with the deprecated async: false method. If I can assign the contents of each .json file to an object using ajax, this may solve my issue.

Comment: `getJSON()` is a shortcut for ajax. It uses the ajax internally. And don't try to do it in a synchronious way. Learn how to think async and use promises as in my example.

Comment: Ahh I see! Sorry I didn't see script.js file on your link before; your methodology should work perfectly! So much cleaner and simpler than my approach too. Thanks!